# I do or I am doing

Tags: word-choice

These sentences are from "English Grammar in Use" Raymond Murphy. If I use present simple instead of present continuous would it be wrong? The book says present continuous means I do that too often more often than normal, but present simple means I do it every time. However can I use present simple in the book's examples?

1. "I've lost my key again. I'm always losing things." Or "I always lose."
2. "You are always watching television. You should do something more active". Or "You always watch."
3. "John is never satisfied. He's always complaining." Or "He always complains."

Comment: Your book is correct! "I always lose things" would mean that you lose every object that is in your possession! "You always watch TV in the evenings" (every evening). "He always complains when X happens" (every time).

Comment: I think it would be better to say that "I'm always losing things" means "I frequently lose things".

Comment: @Kate Bunting, do you mean depending on context present simple is also correct in each? I always lose things= if I want to say I lose all the things I have, I always lose things=every time,  he always complains=every time, he always watches TV =every time?

Comment: Your book says ** present simple means I do it every time.** If you mean to say that something happens annoyingly often, or someone does something too much, it's much more idiomatic to use the continuous tense. We would use the present tense with _always_ to refer to things that literally always happen!

Comment: @Kate Bunting, I understand that but if the following things literary always happen can I use present simple in these: I always lose things= if I want to say I lose all the things I have, I always lose things=every time/always,  he always complains=every time/always, he always watches TV =every time/always?

Comment: I've already told you all that! _You always watch TV_ sounds odd on its own (presumably the person doesn't spend _all_ their time doing so), which is why I added _in the evenings_ to make it seem more natural.

Comment: @Kate Bunting, you said you have already said that. Did you mean "I always lose things" and "he always complains" "he always watches TV in the evenings" are all correct with present simple  but unlike present continuous, present simple doesn't express annoyance?

Comment: Yes! See my second comment above.

Comment: @Kate Bunting, thank you!!!

Comment: Well, it _could_ express annoyance if, for example, you were annoyed that someone behaved in a certain way every time you met. The point is that "He's always doing X" is a figure of speech implying that something happens so often that it _feels_ as though it always happens.

Comment: @Kate Bunting, present simple can express annoyance by intonation, can't it? Unlike present continuous which expresses that by itself. I mean by its construction he  is always doing something.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't.

1. I am always losing things.= I lose things very often/too often than normal. (NOT I always lose thing.) There is a difference between 'I lose things **very often/too often**' and 'I lose things every time'.
2. You are always watching television.= You are watching television very often/too often. (NOT You always watch television.)
3. He's always complaining.= He's complaining very often/too often.

'I always do' and 'I am always doing' have different meanings.

There is a difference between **very often/too often** and **every time**.